# Помогите разобраться с android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: java, android

Смотрите вот какая штука! Пишу приложение по поддержкой интернета. По коду все вроде работает и в манифесте добавил пермишн поддержки интернета(android.permission.INTERNET"). а при компиляциии и установке получается что в приложении интернета как бы нет. Проверял каким макаром: 1. Устанавливал чисто APK и когда его открываешь там пишутся все разрешения которые задействованы, а их там нет... кароче незнаю что делать блин....может вы сталкивались?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: вот такой стоит в манифесте <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: доступ к сетевым соединениям прописали? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Покажите код коим вы список разрешений выводите. И проверять наличие интернета проще всего... попытавшись подключиться к нему (скачать что-то)

Comment: Ну или пермишн в application тэге находится

Comment: В 6 версии андроида так нельзя делать. Нужно запрашивать разрешение непосредственно перед тем, как обращаться к интернету. Разрешения, прописанные в манифесте, при установке не показываются и игнорируются.

Comment: а как запросить разрешение? чет я туплю....

Answer (score 1):

1. В манифесте все-таки нужно прописывать именно так, как указано в вопросе автором.
2. Перед тем, как использовать что-то, требующее отдельного разрешения (интернет, локация, смс и т.д.), просим разрешения так:

`int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);`

Этот код проверяет, есть ли разрешение. Если да, то результат будет `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. Если нет, то результат будет `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`, и надо спрашивать пользователя:

```
public class PermissionsUtils {

//region MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST
public static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
//endregion

public static boolean checkAndRequest(@NonNull final Activity activity, @NonNull final String permission, final int requestCode, String messagePermission, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onCancelListener) {
    boolean result = false;
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage(messagePermission).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", onCancelListener).show();

        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

        }
    } else {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Обработка ответа пользователя (разрешено/запрещено):

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то без изменений....

Comment: Вообще не понимаю что происходит? Может потому что у меня рут права на устройстве, а он на андроид 6?

Comment: Может, в настройках стоит запрет на запросы прав. Насчет рута не знаю, к сожалению.

Что у вас возвращает метод `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)`?

Answer (score 0):

Сам долго бился над данной проблемой. Решил благодаря статье:
[Android 6.0: Doze Mode, App Standby, Runtime Permissions](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269491/)
Вариант решения добавить приложение в настройках Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization ручками или программно.